# Replace the lines if one part of string matches for and writing the same $Variable as it is

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

have a file call `config.php` which contains something like this.

```
<?php
$main="dev.digin.io";
```

What I need to do is, Whatever the string values which contain after `$main=` need be replaced with a content in a shell variable like `$MainDomain`.

Final config.php need to be like this. (consider bash shell variable consist some this like $MainDomain=prod.mail.com )

```
<?php
$main="prod.mail.com";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nasty-looking sed substitution gets you what you want:

```
$ MainDomain=prod.mail.com
$ sed -E "s/^(\\\$main=\")[^\"]+(\";)$/\1$MainDomain\2/" config.php
<?php
$main="prod.mail.com";
```

Add the `-i` switch to edit the file "in-place". Use `-i.bak` to create a backup file `config.php.bak`.

It looks as though the best thing to do in this situation would be to use a configuration file and adjust your PHP code to read from it, as modifying source code like this is a risky business.

Comment: I tired `sed -i "s/^(\\\$mainDomain=\")[^\"]+(\";)$/\1$MainDomain\2/" /var/www/html/include/config.php`
it prints the below in the shell prompt. Any idea ? 

**sed: -e expression #1, char 49: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS**

Comment: You're not using the `-E` switch, which means that capture groups need to be escaped. Add the `-E` switch. Also, you should really be using a backup suffix with `-i`, especially when testing.

Comment: Then it will print the correct out put ot the console. But not modifying the file. Any idea ?

Comment: Use both switches!

Comment: Thanks @Tom it works !

Answer (score 0):

@Daz, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
 awk -vVAR="$MainDomain" '/\$mainDomain/{sub(/=.*/,"="VAR,$0);} 1' Input_file
```

Where -vVAR="$MainDomain" VAR is awk's variable which has shell variable named  MainDomain's value in it. In awk we can't directly shell variable values so this is how we could assign it to a variable of awk and get it used into it.

Let me know if you have any queries on same.